# Quorum private blockchain: Connect to remote server

Tags: transactions, blockchain, private, remix, quorum

i'm beginner in Blockchain and i tried to create a private quorom network with 5 nodes. Actually, i did the same as here:

https://consensys.net/docs/goquorum/en/stable/tutorials/private-network/create-qbft-network/

and it works perfectly for me.

Now i tried to make transactions in this private network from another computer connected to the same network. obviously, in the remix IDE, i used the IP address of the computer hosting the private network (in the external http provider) and the same http port of one of the nodes. but it didn't worked.

My question is: when starting all the nodes of the private blockchain with the geth command, shoud i set the http.addr flag to

1. "localhost" since all the nodes are located in the same computer?
2. "the IP address of the host machine?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

http-add flag defines "from where you'll open http connection".
If you use 127.0.0.1 or localhost, then you'll only be able to connect to the network via http from the same machine as the node(s).
Else, use 0.0.0.0 to allow connection from any source.